# Loading Circle Delayed C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

I have an applicatoion that loads data to a datagrid. However, the loading process taks a feww second. I would like to show a loading circle as the data loads, but the circle doesnt show until the data has completed its loading. The code is:

```
public void processbutton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     pictureBox1.Visible = true;
     Image image=Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Curr\\Projects\\Proj\\Proj\\load.gif");
     pictureBox1.Image = image;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     string ssqlconnectionstring = "string";
     SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring);

     string comm = "SELECT * from Table";
     sqlconn.Open();

//---------------------REST OF CODE-------------------------
```

Comment: So, how do you think that your form will be repainted if the current thread is waiting for your query response :)? Maybe you need do manually ask for the form to repaint or perform the query asynchronously...

Answer (score 0):

You must perform all long running tasks, that would otherwise block the UI thread, from a separate thread.

Look up the `BackgroundWorker` class

Cheers

EDIT:

Or you could use the Task class, like this:

```
public async void processbutton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    Image image=Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Curr\\Projects\\Proj\\Proj\\load.gif");
    pictureBox1.Image = image;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string ssqlconnectionstring = "string";
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring);

        string comm = "SELECT * from Table";
        sqlconn.Open();
        //---------------------REST OF CODE-------------------------            
    });
```